# How to extract text from a edittext using InputConnection.getExtractedText

Tags: android, android-source

normal case its extracted using getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0)
but in the case inputType 0 its get null value so cant extract the text from the input field. Is any idea to extracting new way ?

Comment: If am right, do you want to get the text stored in an edittext?

Comment: yes . I m using a custom keyboard so i need to get the text from current input field

Comment: Have you implemented the `onText()` method?

Comment: The InputConnection interface is the communication channel from an InputMethod back to the application

Comment: how to possible communicate another way

Comment: Sorry I thought it that way. I don't know another method. Sorry I couldn't help you.